# How can I speed up bulk client comparisons/update/inserts with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a WebAPI that accepts an uploaded CSV file and parses the file into Entity objects.  This happens very quickly and leaves me with a list of a little over 1000 objects.  I then need to see if these uploaded Entity objects already exist in the database (i.e. is this an update or an insert).

Rather than have thousands of queries to the database, I read all existing clients and then do my comparisons in memory.  However, this whole process takes WAY to long and my call times out.  Somehow, I need to speed up this code.  Is there anything I could do to speed this up?

```cs
public async Task SaveResultsAsync()
{
   var allExisting = _dbContext.Clients
     .Include(c => c.Bookings)
     .IgnoreQueryFilters()
     .Where(c => c.AgencyId == _agencyId)
     .ToList();

   Client searchItem = null;

   Func<Client,bool> searchFunc = (c) => {
     return c.AgencyReferenceNumber == searchItem.AgencyReferenceNumber ||
       (c.LastName == searchItem.LastName && (c.SSN != null && c.SSN == searchItem.SSN)
       || (c.FirstName == searchItem.FirstName && c.Birthdate.HasValue && searchItem.Birthdate.HasValue 
       && c.Birthdate.Value == searchItem.Value));

    //Its the foreach loop that takes all the time!
    foreach(var client in clients){
       searchItem = client;
       //Searches data queried -- if not found, searches any new clients that have already been added
       var existing = allExisting.FirstOrDefault(searchFunc) ?? _dbContext.Clients.Local.FirstOrDefault(searchFunc);

       if(existing != null){
          //Update existing item
          existing.Birthdate = client.Birthdate;
          ...
          foreach(var booking in client.Bookings)
          {
             var b_existing = existing.Bookings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.AgencyReferenceNumber == booking.AgencyReferenceNumber);
             if(b_existing != null)
             {
                 b_existing.AdmissionTypeId = booking.AdmissionTypeId;
                 ...
             }
             else{
                 c_existing.Bookings.Add(booking);
             }
          }

          if(_dbContext.Entry(c_existing).State != EntityState.Added)
             _dbContext.Update(c_existing);
       }
       else{
          _dbContext.Add(client);
       }
    }

    await _dbContext.BulkSaveChangesAsync() //EntityFramework Extensions 
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect the `foreach` loop to take that long, with only 1000 items, if it's not doing any I/O. Is `existing.Bookings.FirstOrDefault(...)` doing Lazy loading, issuing queries to the database for each booking?

Comment: Even if it's not doing Lazy Loading, if `FirstOrDefault()` there is the `Queryable.FirstOrDefault`, which takes an `Expression<...>`, you should put an `AsEnumerable()` before it so you're passing a precompiled `Func<>`. Otherwise, LINQ to Objects will be recompiling your expression for every Booking.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing where the `AsEnumerable()` would go -- could you show me what you mean by that?

Comment: I was thinking `existing.Bookings.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(...)`. But it sounds like you figured out it's the change tracking that's taking the most time, so I'm not sure how much this would improve things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to speed this all up significantly by adding `.AsNoTracking()` to my initial query for `allExisting` like so:

```cs
var allExisting = _dbContext.Clients
     .AsNoTracking()
     .Include(c => c.Bookings).AsNoTracking()
     .IgnoreQueryFilters()
     .Where(c => c.AgencyId == _agencyId)
     .ToList();
```

Because I am using `_dbContext.Update()` and `_dbContext.Add()`, `SaveChanges()` still knows what to update.

Apparently, the change tracking built into EF must add **much** more overhead than I expected.